# Execute a code after data model migration in Core Data (MagicalRecord)

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I have to data models and a mapping model.
I would like to execute some code after the migration is done between my model v11 and model v12.
How can I do that? I'm using Magical Record.
I tried to do it in endEntityMapping from NSEntityMigrationPolicy, but it is an action that should be done after the entire migration, not in the middle.
Another idea I have is to save a flag in NSUserDefaults in any endEntityMapping and use it (and remove the flag) after my Core Data stack is setup by Magical Record, but this seems a bit workaround.

Comment: you can use setupAutoMigratingCoreDataStack MR will take care of the migration

Comment: I'm already using that. But how do I know if a data model mappings was performed? Thanks.